# Typescript object with keys of union type but with non uniform value types

Tags: typescript, generics

TLDR, what I'm trying to do is create an (object) type, where the key types are matching a literal-union type, but the value types are all different.

Consider the following scenario. We have a set if `PluginId`s (union of string literal types). Each of these represent a plugin (what a plugin is is irrelevant). I'd like to create an object type, where the keys match this union of string literal, and the values are a type unique for the given plugin.

```
// Union of literal types
export type PluginId = 'cat' | 'dog' | 'racoon'

/**
 * - false means plugin is off
 * - true means plugin is on with default config
 * - custom configuration object means on, with custom config
 */
export type Config<T = {}> = boolean | Partial<T>

// Custom config objects, not every plugin has one
export type DogPluginConfig = { woof: boolean }
export type CatPluginConfig = { meow: boolean }

// I'd like each key to be a PluginId here, and I'd like the compiler to enforce this.
export type Configs = {
  cat?: Config<CatPluginConfig>
  dog?: Config<DogPluginConfig>
  racoon?: Config
}

export function instantiatePlugins(configs: Configs): Plugin[] {
  // doesn't matter
}
```

This is what I've got so far, but as it stands currently, there is no link between the keys of `Configs` and `PluginId`.

I've tried utilizing a `Record` type, something like:

```
export type Configs = Partial<Record<PluginId, Config>> & {
  cat?: Config<CatPluginConfig>
  dog?: Config<DogPluginConfig>
}
```

This does halfway what I want to do, but it doesn't enforce that the keys I define on the type after `&` match `PluginId`.

Is there any way I could do what I want?

Comment: Are you *intentionally* pairing `DogPluginConfig` with `cat` and vice versa?  If so, why?  If not, maybe fix it because it's distracting.

Comment: What, specifically, do you want enforced?  Can you show an example of code that compiles where you think it shouldn't?  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mM4BzN) meet your needs?  If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz my bad, bad copy paste. But it absolutely doesn't matter. I'd like to enforce that the keys of `Configs` can only be a `PluginId` without constraining the values of  `Conigs`.

Comment: @jcalz I see, this technically gets me there. What I don't like about it, is that in `BaseConfig` the keys are not enforced to be `PluginId`. So if for some reason `"dog"` changes to `"doggy"`, the compiler won't be aware that this is an issue, and `Dog` will be created with the wrong config.

Comment: Then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAKrkw) meet your needs?  If so I can write that up, if not what is wrong with it?  Also I'm going to fix the remaining `Cat`/`Dog` mixup in your question